# Calling a zero argument template function pointer with variadic template argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-function

Here is a code snippet from a post at [Functional C++](https://functionalcpp.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/generalized-function-evaluation/comment-page-1/#comment-197) blog, describing how a generalized function evaluation can be implemented.

My question is how can you declare template function pointer f like R(C::*f)() with no arguments and still be able to call it with Args…?

```
// functions, functors, lambdas, etc.
template<
    class F, class... Args,
    class = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_member_function_pointer<F>::value>::type,
    class = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_member_object_pointer<F>::value>::type
    >
auto eval(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> decltype(f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// const member function
template<class R, class C, class... Args>
auto eval(R(C::*f)() const, const C& c, Args&&... args) -> R
{
    return (c.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template<class R, class C, class... Args>
auto eval(R(C::*f)() const, C& c, Args&&... args) -> R
{
    return (c.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// non-const member function
template<class R, class C, class... Args>
auto eval(R(C::*f)(), C& c, Args&&... args) -> R
{
    return (c.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// member object
template<class R, class C>
auto eval(R(C::*m), const C& c) -> const R&
{
    return c.*m;
}

template<class R, class C>
auto eval(R(C::*m), C& c) -> R&
{
    return c.*m;
}

struct Bloop
{
    int a = 10;
    int operator()(){return a;}
    int operator()(int n){return a+n;}
    int triple(){return a*3;}
};

int add_one(int n)
{
    return n+1;
}

int main()
{
    Bloop bloop;

    // free function
    std::cout << eval(add_one,0) << "\n";

    // lambda function
    std::cout << eval([](int n){return n+1;},1) << "\n";

    // functor
    std::cout << eval(bloop) << "\n";
    std::cout << eval(bloop,4) << "\n";

    // member function
    std::cout << eval(&Bloop::triple,bloop) << "\n";

    // member object
    eval(&Bloop::a,bloop)++; // increment a by reference
    std::cout << eval(&Bloop::a,bloop) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

For instance, when I try:

```
struct Bloop
{
    int a = 10;
    int operator()(){return a;}
    int operator()(int n){return a+n;}
    int triple(){return a*3;}
    int foo(int n) {return n;}
};

template <typename R, typename C, typename... Args>
void eval (R(C::*func)(), C& c, Args... args) {
    (c.*func)(args...);
}

int main()
{
    Bloop bloop;

    eval(&Bloop::foo, bloop, 5);

    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:27:31: error: no matching function for call to 'eval(int (Bloop::*)(int), Bloop&, int)'
     eval(&Bloop::foo, bloop, 5);
                               ^
main.cpp:27:31: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:19:6: note: template<class R, class C, class ... Args> void eval(R (C::*)(), C&, Args ...)
 void eval (R(C::*func)(), C& c, Args... args) {
      ^
main.cpp:19:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:27:31: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
     eval(&Bloop::foo, bloop, 5);
                               ^
```

And if I declare `func` like `R(C::*func)(int)`, it compiles.

Comment: What is wrong with deducing that function's parameters with second parameter pack (or even the same) like `void eval (R(C::*func)(Params...), C& c, Args... args)` ?

Comment: Yes, this way it worked. But why is it not required in the above code snippet from Functional C++ blog?

Comment: What do you mean by *it is not required in the blog entry*? I think it's just the authors didn't attempt to instantiate this function template with pointer-to-non-zero-parameter-member-functions like you did. also, remember that parameter pack can be empty as well

Comment: No, in ``main()``, he calls ``eval(bloop,4)`` (with an int argument)

Comment: Piotr is right.  I just looked at that code.  The member function they pass is "bloop" which takes zero arguments.  If you change this to take one argument compilation fails as in your example.

Comment: `eval(bloop, 4)` calls the Functor overload, which takes a template argument that doesn't use a function signature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in the blog article is incorrect (or at least incomplete); it only works for no-argument functions.  You could write `eval` more correctly like this:

```
template<class R, class C, class... T, class... Args>
auto eval(R(C::*f)(T...), C& c, Args&&... args) -> R
{
    return (c.*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Note the `T...` parameter pack for arguments to the pointer to member function type.  This is a distinct type pack from `Args&&...` because the two packs could be deduced differently.

Answer (score 1):

This code could be made simultaneously simpler and more generic by avoiding the analysis of the pointer-to-member-function and pointer-to-member-data types and simply accepting anything for which the calls are well-defined:

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) { \
    return (__VA_ARGS__); \
  }

// Function object type
template<class F, class... Args>
auto eval(F&& f, Args&&... args)
RETURNS(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...))

// pointer to member function, object reference
template<class PMF, class C, class... Args>
auto eval(PMF&& pmf, C&& c, Args&&... args)
RETURNS((std::forward<C>(c).*std::forward<PMF>(pmf))(std::forward<Args>(args)...))

// pointer to member data, object reference
template<class PMD, class C>
auto eval(PMD&& pmd, C&& c)
RETURNS(std::forward<C>(c).*std::forward<PMD>(pmd))
```

while we're at it, we may as well support the omitted cases of pointer-to-members with object pointers in addition to object references for completeness, especially given that the sample code requires them to evaluate `eval(&Bloop::a,&bloop)++`:

```
// pointer to member data, object pointer
template<class PMD, class P>
auto eval(PMD&& pmd, P&& p)
RETURNS((*std::forward<P>(p)).*std::forward<PMD>(pmd))

// pointer to member function, object pointer
template<class PMF, class P, class... Args>
auto eval(PMF&& pmf, P&& p, Args&&... args)
RETURNS(((*std::forward<P>(p)).*std::forward<PMF>(pmf))(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9770a0dcb28bbbc)

(Ok, maybe "simpler" was a poor choice of word. "More concise" or "terse" would probably be more accurate.)